# ScreenUtilInit and bottomsheet - Keyboard hiding bottomSheet textfield

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, responsive, bottom-sheet

i used to fix the hidden Bottomsheet using the `isScrollControlled: true`, along with `padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)`, to fix this issue, but lately i started using the ScreenUtilInit for a responsive content; but now the bottomSheet is not shown on the top of the keyboard if a wrap my app with the ScreenUtilInit widget! everythings works fine without it.

anybody could give me a suggestion? (how to avoid this, or a better solution for responsive content) and thanks in advance.

this is my code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(375, 812), 
      builder: (context, child) => MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            isScrollControlled: true,
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      autofocus: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: 'Enter a search term'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: 'Enter a search term'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Scrollable Sheet Example'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Main Content'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this by adding the `useInheritedMediaQuery: true,` like so:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(375, 812), 
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
      builder: (context, child) => MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

thanks to this answer [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126585#issuecomment-1545422080)